# How to control the timestep in NDSolve when using MethodOfLines/Pseudospectral to solve PDE?

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve PDE by `Pseudospectral` Method. Here is the method

```
 mol[n : _Integer | {_Integer ..}, o_: "Pseudospectral"] := 
 {"MethodOfLines", 
"TemporalVariable"->t, 
"SpatialDiscretization" ->{"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints"->n, 
"MinPoints"->n, "DifferenceOrder"->o}}
```

Here `MinPoints/MaxPoints` defines the spatial grid. However, I try to control also the timestep, for example, put a uplimit on timestep. What should I do? Is there something like "MaxTimeStep"?